# Поиск комбинации в массиве и ее инверсия

Tags: c++

Помогите доработать программу , не получается с поиском комбинации и ее инверсией.

```
                               Задание:
```

Исходные данные: файл, созданный в текстовом редакторе содержащий текст, длина которого не превышает 128 символов.
Требуется разработать алгоритм и написать программу, позволяющую::
• выводить данные из файла в битовом виде на экран дисплея;
• с помощью отдельной функции осуществлять поиск введенной пользователем двоичной комбинации и ее замену на инверсную ей комбинацию;
• выводить результат на экран и сохранять в файл.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

void charToBit(char mass[]);
int look(int massBit[]);


void read()
{
    string path = "file.txt";
    cout << "Введите название файла \n";
    //cin >> path;
    ifstream obj;
    obj.open(path);
    if (!obj.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Ошибка открытия файла\n";

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Файл открыт \n";
        char mass[140];
        while (!obj.eof())
        {
            obj.getline(mass,140);
            cout << mass;

        }
        cout << endl;
        obj.close();
        charToBit(mass);
    
    }


    
}

void charToBit(char mass[])
{
    int massBit[1024];
    for (int s = 0, j = 7, k = 0; k < 1024; k++, j--)
    {
        if (j == 0)
        {
            s++;
            j = 7;
        }
        massBit[k] = mass[s] >> j & 1;
        if (k % 70 == 0)
            cout << endl;
        cout << massBit[k];
    }
    cout << endl;
    //look(massBit);
    if (look(massBit) == true)
        cout << "yes\n";
    else
        cout << "no\n";
    
    
}

int look(int massBit[])
{
    const int count = 1024;

    int l = 0;            // нижняя граница
    int u = count-1 ;    // верхняя граница
    int key[6];
    cout << "\nВведите комбинацию \n";
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
     cin >> key[i];
    

    while (l <= u)
    {
        int m = (l + u) ;
        if (massBit[m] == key[l])
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (massBit[m] < key[l])
        {
            l = m + 1;
            return false;
            
        }
        if (massBit[m] > key[l])
        {
            u = m - 1;
            return false;
            
        }
    }
    return 0;
    
} 



int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    read();
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот код почти полного решения. Только я вывожу конвертированный текст в консоль, а не в файл, но с этим проблем быть не должно. Ну и имя файла читаю из аргумента командной строки, а не из консоли.
Возможно решение покажется сложным, попробуйте разобраться. Если что пишите в комментариях, отвечу.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void charsToBits(char mass[]);
int look(const char *massBit);

char    *my_strnstr(const char *big, const char *little, size_t len)
{
    size_t  lenlit;
    size_t  lenbig;
    size_t  i;
    char    *tmp;

    lenlit = strlen((char*)little);
    if (!lenlit)
        return ((char*)big);
    lenbig = strlen((char*)big);
    while (len-- >= lenlit && lenbig-- >= lenlit)
    {
        i = 0;
        tmp = (char*)little;
        while (*tmp && *tmp++ == *(char*)(big + i))
            i++;
        if (i == lenlit)
        {
            return ((char *)big);
        }
        big++;
    }
    return (NULL);
}

void charArrToBitArr(const char *src, char *dest) {
    while (*src) {
        for (int i = 7; i >= 0; --i) {
            *dest = (*src & (1 << i)) ? '1' : '0';
            ++dest;
        }
        ++src;
    }
}

void read(char *file)
{
    ifstream obj;
    obj.open(file);
    if (!obj.is_open()) {
        cout << "Ошибка открытия файла\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Файл открыт \n";
        char mass[129] = {0};
        obj.getline(mass,128);
        cout << mass << endl;
        obj.close();
        charsToBits(mass);
    }
}

void charsToBits(char *mass)
{
    char bits[1025] = {0};
    charArrToBitArr(mass, bits);
    cout << bits << endl;
    if (look(bits))
        cout << "yes\n";
    else
        cout << "no\n";
}

int look(const char *bits)
{
    char key[1025];
    cout << "Введите комбинацию:" << endl;
    cin >> key;
    key[1024] = 0;
    char *subSrtStart = my_strnstr(bits, key, strlen(bits));
    if (!subSrtStart)
        return 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(key); ++i) {
        subSrtStart[i] = subSrtStart[i] == '1' ? '0' : '1';
    }
    cout << bits << endl;
    return 1;

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    (void)argc;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    read(argv[1]);
}
```

**UPD** Изменил текст программы, в связи с замечанием @avp. Программа теперь ищет вхождение последовательности длинной до 1024 символов включительно. Находит только первое вхождение, если нужно найти все вхождения, то нужно `strnstr` вызывать в цикле со смещением строки-источника.
`strnstr` самописная, если не запрещено заданием (в чём я сомневаюсь), то можно её заменить на какую-то библиотечную функцию.

Comment: 1) с нулевыми байтами (все 8 бит 0) работать не будет; 2) а почему поиск только 8-ми битной комбинации? (в условии задачи нет такого ограничения, значит допустимый размер битовой комбинации от 1 до 1024 (это 128 байт) бит)

Comment: @avp по второму пункту согласен, сейчас исправлю. По первому тоже согласен, но не думаю, что туда подадут ноль. Фраза `файл, созданный в текстовом редакторе содержащий текст` к этому не располагает.